# How programmatically to add icon on toolbar in javafx?

Tags: javafx, icons, toolbar

How programmatically(not with FXML file) to add icon on the user created toolbar(not window main bar) in javafx without putting the icon on the button or on the label before?

Answer (score -2):

I have solved it:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
Image image = new Image("file:name.jpg");
imageView.setImage(image);
imageView.setFitHeight(30);
imageView.setFitWidth(30);
toolbar.getItems().add(imageView);
```

Comment: Don’t create a resource URL by hand. This will fail if, eg, you try to run the application on another machine.

Comment: I know. Really the file is in the project directory.
I get it by 
Image image = new Image("file:name.jpg");